# Unable to parse user agent string in java

Tags: java, user-agent

I am receiving the following user agent string

```
["Mozilla/5.0","(Macintosh;","Intel","Mac","OS","X","10.8;","rv:31.0)","Gecko/20100101","Firefox/31.0"]
```

I am trying to parse it as a string and convert it into array of strings,but i am unable to read it as a string.Is there any better way to read a user agent data enclosed in square braces

```
public class AgentParse{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String a="""["Mozilla/5.0","(Macintosh;","Intel","Mac","OS","X","10.8;","rv:31.0)","Gecko/20100101","Firefox/31.0"]""";
        String st=a.replace('[', ' ').replace(']', ' ').replace('(', ' ').replace(')', ' ');
        String[] arr=st.split(",");
        System.out.println(arr[0]);

        }
```

I have a list of such strings and i cannot copy paste every string and do escape characters.I am looking for a data type in java which can hold the above data

Comment: what is the error ? what is your expected output ?

Comment: You have to escape the double quotes in the user agent string

Comment: Java does not have triple-quoted strings.

Comment: @Ravi I have a list of such strings i cannot do escape characters individually for every string.

Comment: @srivathsava you have to escape it otherwise you need to remove all double quote.

Answer (score 0):

From your existing code, you seems to be looking for `Mozilla/5.0` as an output. So, first of all you **need to escape all double quotes**.

```
String str = "[\"Mozilla/5.0\",\"(Macintosh;\",\"Intel\",\"Mac\",\"OS\",\"X\",\"10.8;\",\"rv:31.0)\",\"Gecko/20100101\",\"Firefox/31.0\"]";
System.out.println(str.split(",")[0].replace("[",""));
```

It will output

```
"Mozilla/5.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse all the string.

```
String a = "[\"Mozilla/5.0\",\"(\"Macintosh;\",\"Intel\",\"Mac\",\"OS\",\"X\",\"10.8;\",\"rv:31.0\")\",\"Gecko/20100101\",\"Firefox/31.0\"]";
String[] newArray = a.split(",");
    for (String s : newArray) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

output

```
["Mozilla/5.0"
"("Macintosh;"
"Intel"
"Mac"
"OS"
"X"
"10.8;"
"rv:31.0")"
"Gecko/20100101"
"Firefox/31.0"]
```